# What's the difference between [] and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
>>>list(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>[123]
[123]
```

why the list(123) results to an Exception while the [] works ??

Comment: Because `ints` aren't iterable, the second example is a list literal

Comment: `[]` "arguments" are the elements themselves. `list` takes only one iterable argument

Answer (score 2):

list() is a type constructor
 The thing you put inside the brackets has to be iterable i.e. something that you can iterate though using a loop. Like a string or a list of integers or floats. As an integer itself is not iterable; list(123) gives an error. But if you type list('123'); then it returns a list as [ '1', '2', '3'].

In case of [123] it denotes a list of a single integer 123. So it works. Its just like writing 23 in the interpretor and getting 23 as the result.

Answer (score 2):

For an empty list, using `[]` is much better because it's faster and avoid name look-up

The `list()` built-in is useful to convert some other iterable to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Because `list` is a callable that takes one object as parameter which must be an iterable, while `[]` is list literal and understands that the single int supplied should be the only element for the list.

If you want to use `list`, you have to wrap the number in an iterable, for example `list((123,))`.

Comment: `list` is a function if by function one means a callable, which can be called with arguments.  That is the meaning of function in https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html, which includes all the builtin classes.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list, "Rather than being a function, list is actually a mutable sequence type".  The documentation you linked says it is a list of "functions and types"

Comment: That is a bad edit that should be reverted.  None of the other built-in classes that I looked at have such a note.  There is nothing special about `list` in this regard.

Comment: Considering you have much more experience with the ins and outs of Python than I do, I'll take your word for it :P  The clarification seems to have been introduced around the 3.2 docs

Comment: well, it's listed on the built-in function page, yet it's not really a function, so I'd be precise and call it a callable.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Most of the builtin types’ docs in functions.html are weird, and have been for a long time. IIRC, some of the others are documented like `list`, some are explicitly called functions, and the way `dict` is written it sounds like it returns the type rather than an instance of it. The rewrite around 2.2 wasn’t perfect, but I think the later changes have only made them worse.

Comment: Anyway, given that there isn’t a more specialized term for “functions, bound methods, builtin functions, builtin unbound methods, and types”, I think `callable` is the best term to use to be correct without being pedantic, so the answer is fine about that.

Comment: @abarnert I opened https://bugs.python.org/issue34118.  I agree that the dict entry could be improved, so intend to use the set entry as the model for the collection classes.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax of list() constructor is:

```
list([iterable])
```

And int is not iterable. so..

Comment: This is misleading. Those brackets mean the `iterable` is optional, so you can call `list()` to get an empty list, but out of context it looks like you're saying that you have to put the iterable in brackets—e.g., to create a list out of the tuple `2, 3, 4` you have to write `list([2, 3, 4])` (which does, of course, work, but that only makes it more confusing.)

Comment: Of course it's optional, I assume that a programmer is used to read such kind of 
 technical docs...

Comment: Someone who could read and understand language reference docs without any explanation wouldn’t have asked this question.